# save the results of a pdf to text conversion displayed in the Console of R Studio in .txt format

Tags: r, tm

I am relatively new with R. I am trying to convert a pdf to a text using the code below.

```
library(tm)
file<-list.files("G:\\FlashPointTest\\Test1\\test")
file<-list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
file

Rpdf<-readPDF(control = list(text="-layout"))
Myfile<-Corpus(URISource(file,encoding = "UTF-8"), readerControl = list(reader=Rpdf))
Myfile
inspect(Myfile[[2]])
```

Everything work fine in terms of accuracy. However I'd like to save the results of a pdf to text conversion (after the "inspect" command) displayed in the Console of R Studio in .txt format. Please see attachment

I tried but got the result :

> error: "cannot coerce class "c("VCorpus", "Corpus")" to a data.frame"

Please Help. Thanks [Cannot Coerce Class Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTBKA.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write corpus text to disk, you can use the `writeCorpus` function from the `tm` package

In your case `writeCorpus(Myfile)` would write all the documents in the corpus to disk as seperate files (assuming you have multiple documents in the corpus).

Do you only the first the document `writeCorpus(Myfile[1])`.

You can also change the path or filenames. Just check the documentation with `writeCorpus`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. your description reflect what I am doing. However, I tried "writeCorpusMyfile[2]", and I got error: "Error: length(x) == length(filenames) is not TRUE" or " cannot open compressed file". Thanks again for your help.

Comment: what happens when you do `writeCorpus(Myfile)`?

Comment: Finally The solution has worked perfectly. I have been able to extract every document in the corpus and save it in an .txt format. Many thanks , You just saved my day!!!

Comment: Hi Phiver. Where to go to accept answers. (I am new on the platform). Thanks